# How to force ansible apt upgrade to install new configuration files (force-confnew)

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, upgrade, dpkg

I have an Ubuntu 18 LTS host which I want to upgrade via ansible and force `apt-get dist-upgrade` to install any new configurations available overwriting any existing ones, as if I was there pressing the first option of that dialog:
[image: apt-get dist-upgrade dialog]

I'm looking into the ansible [apt_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html) documentation and cannot get this to work. In all cases my touched configurations are maintained, and the new vendor ones are stored in `.ucf-dist` files.

So far I've tried:

```
# 1:
ansible -i my-hosts foo -m apt -a 'update_cache=yes upgrade=safe dpkg_options=force-confnew'

# 2:
ansible -i my-hosts foo -m apt -a 'force_apt_get=yes update_cache=yes upgrade=safe dpkg_options=force-confnew'

# 3:
ansible -i my-hosts foo -m apt -a 'force_apt_get=yes update_cache=yes upgrade=dist dpkg_options=force-confnew'
```

FYI I reproduce this locally with VirtualBox snapshots where I revert after every test.

Answer (score 2):

That dialog comes from the UCF framework, which attempts to be a bit smarter about configuration files than `dpkg`'s regular config file handling.

According to the [manual page for ucf](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/ucf/ucf.1.en.html) you can set an environment variable `UCF_FORCE_CONFFNEW` to instruct it to always overwrite the configuration file.

That is different from using `dpkg --force-confnew` though, because it only applies to packages using UCF.